# Zoom into specific part of screen

Tags: windows, windows-10, display

Is there an easy way to zoom into a specific part of my screen and lock the position? I’ve tried using Windows Magnifier but it moves around with the mouse, and with the mouse setting turned off it’s difficult to position.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you could use Magnifier with Lens (Ctrl+Alt+L) view. And you can change the size of the lens using the sliders in the menu as the following screenshot.

You’ve got three different options for the type of zoom you can use on your screen.

**Docked** gives you a half and half view, so one side of your screen is normal, and the other half is zoomed in.

**Full screen** brings up the zoom across your whole monitor.

**Lens** (which in our opinion is the most useful for most scenarios) is a smaller box of magnification which follows your mouse around the screen, whilst the rest of the screen stays at normal magnification.

[image]

**Example**

[image]

Comment: That doesn’t really work for me. I need to be able to select a position and upscale it so it fits my screen, kind of like how the snipping tool works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.blacksunsoftware.com/screenmagnifier.html

This software allows you to zoom into a specific part of my screen and lock the position.

Can be locked to a particular position.

It's free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use windows magnifier tool, just hold the windows key and hit the plus key (Win+'plus') to engage the tool. Win+Esc to exit when you're done.

To make it behave as described by OP, some preparation is required:

Open Windows's Settings... Ease of Access... Magnifier.

Under "Choose a view", select "Docked" view. Once you do this, there are four checkboxes below, labelled "Enable magnifier to follow"; untick them all. Now the magnifier will only magnify the one specific place on your screen.

After engaging the magnifier tool (Win+plus), press Ctrl+Alt+L to engage Lens mode to follow the mouse cursor to the specific area you want to magnify. Now Press Ctrl+Alt+D to change to 'Docked' mode, and it will stick there.

You can move and resize the docked magnified area like a normal window, and zoom in and out by using Win+plus or Win+Minus.

Hope that helps.